# Is it possible to match N elements with a coffeescript splat?

Tags: coffeescript

Is it possible to specify how many elements a splat should match? Something like:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[firstThree...(3), fourth, rest...] = foo

console.log firstThree      // [1, 2, 3]
console.log forth           // 4
console.log rest            // [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of adding a limit to the amount of arguments a splat can take.

But you can use ranges(search for `range` in the [Loops and Comprehensions Docs](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)) to get a similar syntax in your destructuring assignment:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[firstThree, fourth, rest] = [foo[0..2], foo[3], foo[4..-1]]

firstThree
# => [1, 2, 3]
fourth
# => 4
rest            
# => [5, 6]
```